# Finding ongoing Recurring Contributions

Tags: civicontribute

I am trying to find contacts who have live recurring contributions, and by that, I mean recurring contributions that will continue to give, not single contributions that were given as part or a recurring contributions series, and also not recurring contributions series that were cancelled in the past. (I find the terminology here confusing.)

How can I search for all contacts with live recurring contributions that have not been cancelled?

If it's in the docs, I'm sorry, please point out where! Thank you.

Version CiviCRM 4.6.38 (upgrading very soon!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Recurring contributions report and summary report which allows you do filters and also some related fields. You can find them under Contribution reports section(/civicrm/report/template/list?reset=1&compid=2).

Also there is an extension called '[RECURRING CONTRIBUTION SEARCH](https://civicrm.org/extensions/recurring-contribution-search)' that allows you to search recurring contribution.

Cheers

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any per-contact flag maintained in Civi to indicate if someone is a recurring contributor. Therefore, the best you can do is search for contacts who have recently made a recurring contribution. e.g.

- Search | Advanced Search
- Display Settings For Results

  - Display results as: Contacts
- Contributions

  - Contribution is Recurring? Yes
  - Date received: Last 60 days including today